# How to prevent errors with TRY/CATCH expecting conversation TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is the table that I am using for my data.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TSQLUsers

CREATE TABLE TSQLUsers    
(    
    TSQLUserKey int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Birthdate date NOT NULL,
    CreatedOn datetime DEFAULT(GETDATE()) NOT NULL,
    UpdatedOn datetime DEFAULT(GETDATE()) NOT NULL,
    Active bit DEFAULT(1) NOT NULL
)
```

Below is the question I am trying to solve

```
/* Question #2 - 10 points - Create a stored procedure to add users to the TSQLUsers table.  

Your stored procedure should do the following:

- Check first to see if the email address exists in the user table
already.  If it does, display or return a message indicating this and
do not insert the record.
- Make sure the email address is a ".com", has an @ symbol, and is at
least 10 characters in total.  (as we really won't check for a valid
email address in TSQL).
- Wrap your code in a try/catch block and return a message stating 
something broke your code if an error is caught

Once your stored procedure is complete and in place, write SQL to
execute it three times - two good records, and one that fails on the
email address being duplicated.  
*/
```

Below is my code so far

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE InsertUser
    (@firstName varchar(100),
     @lastName varchar(100),
     @email varchar(100),
     @Birthdate date,
     @Success int OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT Email FROM TSQLUsers WHERE Email = @email)
        BEGIN TRY
            IF CHARINDEX ('.com', @email) > 0
                IF CHARINDEX ('@', @email) > 0
                    INSERT INTO TSQLUsers (firstName, LastName, Email, Birthdate) 
                    VALUES (@firstName, @lastName, @email, @Birthdate)

                SET @Success = 1
            END
            ELSE
                SET @Success = 0
            END
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END CATCH



DECLARE @Outcome int = -1

EXEC InsertUser 'Tom', 'Dom', 'tdom@gmail.com', '11/17/1998', @Success=@Outcome OUTPUT

EXEC InsertUser 'Wayne', 'Song', 'tdom@gmail.com', '11/17/1978', @Success=@Outcome OUTPUT

EXEC InsertUser 'Schmarg', 'Thurson', 'tddom@gmail.com', '11/17/1928', @Success=@Outcome OUTPUT
```

I am using SQL Server and I am trying to wrap the statement into a try catch but no matter where I put the try catch it keeps giving me errors. Either saying expected conversion on the catch for an error on the try saying expected catch.

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: You need a `END` after the `END CATCH` to close the `BEGIN` block. Also, you need a `GO` after the `END` to in order to execute the batch to create the stored procedure.

Comment: And you need to post your errors verbatim not summarised in your own words.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE InsertUser(
    @firstName varchar(100),
    @lastName varchar(100),
    @email varchar(100),
    @Birthdate date,
    @Success int OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT Email FROM TSQLUsers WHERE Email = @email
    )

    BEGIN TRY
    if CHARINDEX('.com', @email) > 0
    and CHARINDEX('@', @email) > 0
    begin
        INSERT TSQLUsers (firstName, LastName, Email, Birthdate) 
        VALUES (@firstName, @lastName, @email, @Birthdate)
        SET @Success = 1
    END
    ELSE
        SET @Success = 0
    --END
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END CATCH

    end
```

Comment: You have an `end` with no `begin`